# Android M permission Model : Asking for permission used by external jar

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have to add some permissions to my Manifest (eg: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).

Do I have to handle permission request on my app if the target is API 23? If so, how do I have to proceed?

EDIT:
the JAR I am using is launched as a service in the background, so the call to the methods requiring the permission are made on the JAR and not inside my application code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to handle permission request on my app if the target is API 23?

Yes.

> If so, how do I have to proceed?

[The same way as you do for any other runtime permission requirement](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). The fact that a third-party JAR is involved does not matter. Before you can use something that needs the runtime permission, you need to ask for the permission.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. Because the JAR I am using is launched as a service in the background, so the call to the methods requiring the permission are made on the JAR and not inside my application code.

Comment: @skirix: You would need to request the permissions from the user before the service would be started. Worst-case, you will have to do it when your app starts, if the user has not already granted you the permission.